# События при нажатии мышкой на часть карты.

Tags: canvas, html5

Добрый день! У меня такой вот вопрос: у меня есть карта одного из регионов нашей Родины,её нужно встроить в html страницу, необходимо сделать так чтобы при выделении некоторого района пользователем выполнялось какая либо команда, например запускался php-скрипт.

Теперь сам вопрос как это лучше сделать, саму карту могу в любом формате сделать, думаю может что-то типа canvas задействовать, кто как считает, что использовать?

Comment: ля карт есть хорошая библиотека [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/)

Comment: Да мне не нужно прям карту, у меня просто изображение региона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [HTML тег Area](http://htmlbook.ru/html/area)

Ну или сделать карту [на LibCanvas](http://libcanvas.github.com/)

Comment: Спасибо! Первое --- это то что мне нужно.